# Random redirect 301 only in Firefox

Tags: php, .htaccess, firefox, redirect, mod-rewrite

On page that I create there seems to show up a random redirect 301. By random I mean, people are using page normally then suddenly someday one of the links on page starts to redirect to index page - and that link worked before and is working on other computers but not on this one cause Redirect 301 is cached permanently. Also this doesn't happen on Google Chrome - at least no one using Chrome reported such bug.
One of the redirects in firefox cache:
[Firefox redirect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tN9z.png)

Page is on Joomla! and my htaccess looks like this:

```
    ##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Defining MIME types to ensure the web server actually knows about them.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/javascript          js
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz 
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
</Ifmodule>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compressing output.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</Ifmodule>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Turning off ETags
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag 

# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fixing headers expire time
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  #ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  #ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes


## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.

RedirectMatch 302 /pl/component/tags/tag/([^/]+) /pl/zasoby-strony/tagi/$1
RedirectMatch 302 /pl/dla-mieszkanca/kalendarz/(.+)\-[^0-9]\/? /pl/dla-mieszkanca/kalendarz/$1
RedirectMatch 302 /pl/component/dpcalendar/event/(.+)\-[^0-9]\/? /pl/dla-mieszkanca/kalendarz/$1

#http://localhost/um-ostrowiec/pl/?option=com_dpcalendar&view=event&id=10&Itemid=180

## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

I am having a really hard time with this. And I don't even know how to debug - so my question is, what the hell is doing this and how can I find it? I really appreciate some guidance. :/

EDIT1:

```
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:07:16:44 +0100] "GET /pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/206-rodziny-wielodzietne-karta-duzej-rodziny-ostrowiecka-rodzina-3 HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/206-rodziny-wielodzietne-karta-duzej-rodziny-ostrowiecka-rodzina-3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:07:40:22 +0100] "GET /pl/sfera-spoleczna/program-ostrowiecka-rodzina-3/241-zasady-otrzymania-karty-rodzina-3 HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/sfera-spoleczna/program-ostrowiecka-rodzina-3/241-zasady-otrzymania-karty-rodzina-3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:07:41:37 +0100] "GET /pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/210-pomoc-dla-uczniow-stypendia-szkolne HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/210-pomoc-dla-uczniow-stypendia-szkolne" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:10:05:17 +0100] "GET /pl/samorzad/rada-miasta/387-radni HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/samorzad/rada-miasta/387-radni" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:11:03:47 +0100] "GET /pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/209-fundusz-alimentacyjny HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/209-fundusz-alimentacyjny" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:11:49:46 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 301 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:14:26:45 +0100] "GET /pl/nieruchomosci/informator/379-oznacz-swoja-nieruchomosc-numer-i-nazwa-ulicy-nafroncie-budynku HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/nieruchomosci/informator/379-oznacz-swoja-nieruchomosc-numer-i-nazwa-ulicy-nafroncie-budynku" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [25/Jan/2016:15:22:22 +0100] "GET /pl/samorzad/urzad-miasta/wydzialy-urzedu-miasta/wydzial-spraw-obywatelskich/454-referat-dzialalnosci-gospodarczej HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/samorzad/urzad-miasta/wydzialy-urzedu-miasta/wydzial-spraw-obywatelskich/454-referat-dzialalnosci-gospodarczej" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [26/Jan/2016:07:47:33 +0100] "GET /pl/samorzad/rada-miasta/387-radni HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/samorzad/rada-miasta/387-radni" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [26/Jan/2016:08:11:24 +0100] "GET /pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/209-fundusz-alimentacyjny HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/209-fundusz-alimentacyjny" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [26/Jan/2016:09:24:49 +0100] "GET /pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/219-szkolenia-dla-doroslych HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/sfera-spoleczna/wsparcie-co-gdzie-jak/219-szkolenia-dla-doroslych" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 10.1.1.72 - - [26/Jan/2016:09:49:34 +0100] "GET /pl/nieruchomosci/informator/379-oznacz-swoja-nieruchomosc-numer-i-nazwa-ulicy-nafroncie-budynku HTTP/1.1" 301 822 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/pl/nieruchomosci/informator/379-oznacz-swoja-nieruchomosc-numer-i-nazwa-ulicy-nafroncie-budynku" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [26/Jan/2016:09:53:05 +0100] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_docman HTTP/1.1" 301 1010 "http://inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=articles" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl:80 192.168.10.254 - - [26/Jan/2016:13:10:35 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 301 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

Could this be connected with my other strange problem? [Joomla random lack of permission to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031929/joomla-random-lack-of-permission-to-access)

Comment: Did you check the access log of apache if it issued a 301 header? Do that, it will tell us if it is an issue caused by the server or by the client. Most likely it's the server, but you never know.

Comment: The domain of the Location header in your screenshot – is that your site’s domain, or a completely different one?

Comment: @Charlotte I don't have access to apache log - I'll ask my host admin for it. I also have strange issue with Joomla editing rights. Often users get message 403 - You don't have permission to edit article (or something like that) when they try to edit it and if they try again (few times) they will get access eventually - can those two problems be related? I'll be back when I get hands on that log. :)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - I did get that log, there are 301 redirects but none of which redirects to inwestor3.um.ostrowiec.pl/index.php (added the log to question). Any more clues? Can this be in any way connected with lack of answer from server - people report me that sometimes site doesn't respond and I checked it (with ping), sometime it loses packet. :/ And what are those redirects in the log, there are pointing to the same page but without HTTP/1.1